# Python: re.sub changes nothing

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
def gettextbyxpath(tree, xpath):
    node = tree.xpath(xpath)[0]
    try:
        text = etree.tostring(node, method="text", encoding='UTF-8').strip()
        text = re.sub(' +',' ', text)
        text = re.sub('\n+','\n', text)
        text = re.sub('\n \n','\n', text)
    except:
        text = 'ERROR'
    return text
```

With the last line I try to get rid of lines with just a single space in them. There are quite a lot of them in real data.

When I run the code above as an isolated test it works fine, but in real code the last line doesn't do anything at all! I've tried comparing files generated with and without it - there are no differences.

Example input:

```
        Brand：

   777,Royal Lion



    Main Products:

           battery, 777, carbon zinc, paper jacket,
```

I'm trying to get rid of the vertical white space between the lines.

Any ideas of why my code could be behaving like this?

Comment: Have you checked for CRLF (`\r\n`) line endings?

Comment: You must use raw strings for your patterns or escape the backslashes.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, I you sure? I meant NEWLINE symbol there.

Comment: @MInner: yes because it is inside a pattern. a literal `\n` is seen as a symbol for newline in a regex

Comment: Just to make sure, you're not reading the string line by line, are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to why your code behaves the way you described: The value of `text` that you obtain from the second call to `re.sub` does not contain the pattern you are trying to substitute in your last call to `re.sub`:

```
>>> text = re.sub('\n+', '\n', text) # 2nd call to re.sub
>>> text
>>> 'Brand：\n 777,Royal Lion\n Main Products:\n battery, 777, carbon zinc, paper jacket,'
```

So, you need to remove the second `\n` from the pattern in your last call to `re.sub`:

```
text = re.sub('\n ','\n', text)
```

This will yield:

```
Brand：
777,Royal Lion
Main Products:
battery, 777, carbon zinc, paper jacket,
```

---

**Alternative solution**

```
def gettextbyxpath(tree, xpath):
    node = tree.xpath(xpath)[0]
    try:
        text = etree.tostring(node, method="text", encoding='UTF-8').strip()
        text = '\n'.join(line.strip() for line in text.split('\n') if line.strip())
    except:
        text = 'ERROR'
    return text
```

**Output**

```
Brand：
777,Royal Lion
Main Products:
battery, 777, carbon zinc, paper jacket,
```

What's different about this approach is that *instead of doing successive substitutions* with `re.sub` we split the output of `etree.tostring` at `\n`. Then, we filter the result of that to exclude all lines that are reduced to the empty string when calling `.strip()` on them. This leaves us with just the lines that have actual content, with all white space removed from the left and right side. To get the final result, we join the lines with a single newline (`\n`).

Comment: No way. The thing is: when I run code like this `s = re.sub('\n\n', '\n', s)` or whatever in a separate script (some "testing environment") - it works just fine. But in real world it doesn't. I can't even wonder why.

Comment: @MInner Could you be a bit more specific about what you mean by "real world"?

Comment: Python 2.7 crawler on my local machine that crawls web using urlopen and lxml. I have updated code in the question. Node: there are spaces in the starting of the line.

Comment: @MInner OK, it seems like you need a solution that makes less assumptions about what the content you get actually looks like in terms of white space and newlines. I'll edit my answer to include an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should remove, tab, new lines, and spaces except single space.

```
import re

a ="""
 Brand：

 777,Royal Lion



 Main Products:

 battery, 777, carbon zinc, paper jacket,
"""
p = re.compile(r'[\n\t]+|[ ]{2,}')
print p.sub('',a)
```